# How to use 'line-height' without increasing size of <span>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the header of www.codecademy.com, but I'm having an issue with the 'Upgrade to Pro' button. As per the tutorial I'm following, I'm just using a  because it's purely visual.

In order to center the `<span>`, I use `line-height: 50px` 50px is the height of the header it's placed in. All is fine until I add a border... with `line-height` in the code, the border takes the height of the parent (header which is 50px) instead of wrapping the `<span>` like it does without the `line-height`.

Make the JSFiddle result screen large to see what I mean:

[JSFiddle with line-height](https://jsfiddle.net/kaio37k/st26so58/3/)

[JSFiddle WITHOUT line-height](https://jsfiddle.net/kaio37k/st26so58/4/)

Line-height was the only way I could center the span vertically, no other way worked for me.

How can I wrap the border around the span while keeping line-height?

Comment: Just add an intermediate div?

Comment: @Maxime Chéramy I tried that but the issue that came with it was that the border would then just extend its height to that div, which I could make *look* like it's normal but hopefully there's a way to make it legitimately still wrap the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
     <span id="span1">Catalog</span>
     <span id="span1">Community</span>
     <span id="spanUpgrade">Upgrade to Pro</span>
```

You could do that:

```
     <span class="span1">Catalog</span>
     <span class="span1">Community</span>
     <span class="span1"><span id="spanUpgrade">Upgrade to Pro</span></span>
```

`span1` is a menu item and `spanUpgrade` is something specific to an item.

https://jsfiddle.net/s0Lw4dhc/1/

Comment: I would especially recommend to remove the use of ID like this

Comment: You're right! So many things that I would do differently... But yes, multiple elements with the same ID isn't a good idea :)